# Automation Script vs Export Template

Tags: azure

I'm puzzled with the "automation script" vs "export template" in the Resource manager blade. So many sources are mixing those two things, my understanding is that "automation script" was introduced later, but I'm might be wrong.
When I switched the language (English to German) it's saying actually "automation script", so I'm not sure if that's really an UI issue, and why so many different sources have sometimes "automation script" (which I'm getting only in German) or sometimes "export templates"?

https://pasteboard.co/I75s2jJ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are 2 different names for the same thing. its actually an api call you can perform without the portal as well. just an inconsistency within UI.

Api call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/exporttemplate

Comment: thank you forseeseven.... :) I thought about the same, this inconsistency should be really reported to Microsoft, so they need to patch UI.
Thanks, Stan.

Comment: yes, will accept it! I made a feedback also on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/export-templates, the page shows clearly the "automation script", though title matches, Microsoft needs to fix the documentation and some translation as well, for the external resources, they can't be responsible for sure.

Comment: it used to be called automation script, so I guess they decided to rename, but its not so easy to rename things ;)